# SymbolSource Nightmare

Tags: nuget

So after hours of jumping through hoops, I have gotten SymbolSource running except I am unable to push any packages.  The error I am getting now is:

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 
418 (Reading package metadata failed: The schema version of 'MyNugetPackage' 
is incompatible with version 2.1.31002.9028 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet
to the latest version from See http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/Help 
for possible reasons. Fiddler may help diagnosing this error if your client
discards attached detailed information.).
```

First problem is that you can no longer download the command line version of v2.1.3 of Nuget.  I tried the the oldest version available: v2.8.6 but I get the same error.  Second problem is it looks like SymbolSource.Server.Basic hasn't been touched in 3 years.  Is this project dead?  Am I wasting my time?  I can't find any other alternative for debugging nuget packages without publishing to a third party service (which my company won't allow)?

Comment: I have started to use the basic version of ProGet, which at the time of this writing is available to download with a perpetual free license (http://inedo.com/proget/download).  I can't say enough good things about it.  Simple install, worked right out of the box as both a nuget server and nuget symbol source.  Love it.  If needs ever exceed the basic version, will be happy to buy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Symbol Server project master branch hasn't been touched for 4 years as of writing, and there is a queue of pull requests and issues left open for even longer.

There is an 'upgrade' branch which hasn't been touched since 2014, but that has updated NuGet version.

There is a slightly more recent fork at https://github.com/TrabacchinLuigi/SymbolSource.Community/tree/upgrade
which uses more recent versions of NuGet. Also have a look at the GitHub 'network' for other potential maintained forks: https://github.com/SymbolSource/SymbolSource.Community/network

And alternative hosting solutions include:

- https://inedo.com/proget
- https://github.com/GitTools/GitLink

Edit -- I got my own version running:
https://github.com/i-e-b/SymbolSourceSane

Comment: I went with the free version of ProGet and have been very happy ever since.  I've been using it for about 6 months now.